# How to get a JSON in a POST request in PHP

Tags: php, python, json

The issue is, that I am sending a JSON file in a POST request but i don't know how to get the data from the request itself
Here is the python script that sends the POST request:

```
import json
import httplib
filepath = 'example.txt'
with open(filepath) as fp:  
   line = fp.readline()
   line2 = fp.readline(9)
   jsonbaloo = {}
   jsonbaloo["name"] = line
   jsonbaloo["score"]= line2
   result = json.dumps(jsonbaloo)
def post_dict():
 headers = {"Content-type": "application/json", "Accept": "text/plain"}
 conn = httplib.HTTPConnection('altrevista.org')
 conn.request("POST", "/", result, headers)
post_dict()
```

I want to get the JSON data server side, so I can put it on an SQL database, but I can't program in PHP.

PHP SCRIPT:

```
<?php

function detectRequestBody() {
    $rawInput = fopen('php://input', 'r');
    $tempStream = fopen('php://temp', 'r+');
    stream_copy_to_stream($rawInput, $tempStream);
    rewind($tempStream);
    return $tempStream;
}
?>
```

Comment: Is there any reason to stream this? You are writing to a file on the server, right?

Comment: i want to save this to a SQL database on the server

Comment: OK - are you writing the JSON to a file? What is the end result of your Python code?

Comment: the end result is a POST request containing a JSON... this is sent to the server @JayBlanchard

Comment: I don't see you invoking your `detectRequestBody()` function

Comment: still nothing... @JayBlanchard

Comment: Can you try to do this without the function being involved?

Answer (score 0):

conn.read() to get the response back

Comment: i meant to get the response server side so i can do stuff with it

Answer (score 0):

Since you're writing to a file, you can read from the file using PHP with [`fopen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) or [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).

Using `fopen()`:

```
$fileHandle = fopen("path/to/example.txt", "r");
```

Using `file_get_contents()`:

```
$fileString = file_get_contents("path/to/example.txt");
```

Comment: i have tried that to no avail. the php page shows nothing

Comment: Do you have any errors when you try to open the file? Are you sure the file is being written?

Comment: Can you edit your post and show the PHP script you're using to try to read the file? Have you checked the error logs?

Comment: No. You have to post the code here. Not going to visit any links. None of us are. I am flagging that comment.

Comment: Please do not dump code in a comment, it is unreadable. Edit your original post to add any additional information or code.

Comment: `$jsonPhpObject=json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));`

Comment: He is writing a text file @ivanivan, so no need for `php://input`

Comment: still nothing :( it's still a blank page when i send the JSON, although the request is going through and being accepted by the server, but it is not visible to me and i cant work with it... maybe i should regularly update it?

Comment: Are you writing the JSON to a file?

Comment: no, i am sending the JSON to the server, then to a server-side database

Answer (score 0):

You should receive the data using file_get_contents (php://input stream) and convert it to an array using json_decode.

```
// Retrieve the Post JSON data
$input = file_get_contents('php://input');

// Convert to json to array
$array = json_decode($input, true);

// View the content of the array
print_r($array);
```